# Value read from plot inconsistent with value from direct evaluation

Tags: plotting, numerics

I have  a hypergeometric function. When I plot it, the plotted value at $a=110$ doesn't match the value I get from direct evaluation.

```
Plot[Hypergeometric2F1[1 + a, 1 - a, 52, .9], {a, 100, 110}]
```

From the plot, for $a=110$, I got the value of hypergeometric function is $-4.12\times 10^{-7}$. But when I try to find out by direct evaluation of

```
Hypergeometric2F1[1 + a, 1 - a, 5/2, .9] /. a -> 110
```

I get $1.7867 \times 10^{15}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a plotting problem, you have a numerics problem. Machine arithematic isn't good enough to get an accurate value for

```
Hypergeometric2F1[1 + a, 1 - a, 5/2, .9] /. a -> 110
```

but you are forcing the computation to be made with machine arithmetic by giving .9 as the 4th argument. However, if you substitute 9/10 for .9, you will get a result consistent with your plot.

```
Hypergeometric2F1[1 + a, 1 - a, 5/2, 9/10] /. a -> 110 // N
```

> `6.72304*10^-6`

Comment: The OP could also use [`arbitrary precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html), e.g., `Hypergeometric2F1[1 + a, 1 - a, 5/2, 0.9\`20] /. a->110`